# React Native where to find APPID

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make my React-Native app redirect to the store so users can update the app faster instead of searching for it.
I found a package which helps me with getting the store links.
For the android it asks for the `packageName` which I got. For the IOS however it asks for `appID` and I don't know where to find it.

Any ideas on how I could locate this ID? Google isn't very much of help because so much SEO on apple's side I get iCloud results.

Comment: The app's ID is a unique ID in iTunes Connect. Something like: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/APP_NAME/id*XXXX*

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps to get the appID:

1. Go to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/
2. Click on **"My Apps"**
3. **Select the app** you need the appId of
4. To the left of the page, you will find `App Information` under **General** Header.
5. Click on the **"App Information"** button.
6. Scroll down to `General Information` and find the "**Apple Id**"(AppId) of your application.

That should do it! Cheers